# Passing values to htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a htaccess file for redirection

the redirected content is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -location&action=photos&page=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sitename/view.php?link=$1&action=photos&page=&1
 [L,QSA]
```

The page numer is dynamically passing from the page 
How we can get the page number here pls helpme

Comment: Can you provide the link example you want to rewrite? I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your headline: You cannot pass values to a .htaccess file.

You can however generate the .htaccess file by a script, if that helps you.

Regarding your sample code, maybe this is what you like to achieve:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -location&action=photos&page=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)&page=(.*)$ /sitename/view.php?link=$1&action=photos&page=$2
 [L,QSA]
```

Using this you can access the link via $1 and the page via $2